# Water mark warning in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been seeing lots of error as follows:

```
"[2015-03-29 14:58:25,485][WARN ][cluster.routing.allocation.decider] [Tess-One] high disk watermark [10%] exceeded on [jhQ1qG09T_WtMeAgDj1RbQ][Tess-One] free: 3.7gb[3.1%], shards will be relocated away from this node"
```

What does this mean? Where can I get more information on this?